# Finding the initial velocity of projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, energy-conservation, projectile

What is the formula for calculating initial velocity of projectile using the conservation of energy given the mass, height, angle ?

Comment: What have you done? How have you approached this problem. What is your level of understanding of projectile motion?

Answer (score 1):

Initial kinetic energy is $K_1=\frac{1}{2} m (v_x^2+v_y^2)$ with potential energy $U_1=0$. At the apogee, the potential energy is $U_2=m g h$ and the kenetic energy is $K_2=\frac{1}{2}m v_x^2$.

Equate the two sums to get your answer.

$$U_1+P_1 = U_2 + P_2 $$
$$0+\frac{1}{2} m (v_x^2 + v_y^2) = m g h + \frac{1}{2} m v_x^2 $$
$$ \frac{1}{2} m v_y^2 = m g h$$

SO you can estimate the initial *vertical* velocity $v_y$ from the height $h$.

Note that is assumes the horizontal velocity $v_x$ is constant.

Comment: Doesn't work as it doesn't account for residual velocity at the apogee. Essentially this would only work for projectiles fired upwards.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I assumed vertical motion only.

Comment: I edited the answer for the more general case.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Where U is the intial velocity,g is the gravitational constant,R is the range of the projectile and ∅ is the launch angle between the projectile and the flat ground (imagine the flat ground as the x-axis with the projectile inclined at an angle ∅ on it).

Comment: I think this is the formulate for the range. _OP_ is asking about max height.

Comment: @ja72-he is not asking max height.he is asking for initial velocity which can be easily calculated from this formula by  transposition.

Comment: He is asking for the initial velocity from the max. height. How is the range going to help here is it is not given?

Comment: @ja72-how can it be done from max height?